# How to pass variable to other modules with NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to pass my logServiceClient object to all other modules included in server.js file. When I run below code it prints empty object;

```
logServiceClient{}
```

Is there any way to pass logServiceClient to all other included modules?

server.js file;

```
....
const logger = new Logger({
   level: new CLevel('warn'),
   ordered
}) 

var logServiceClient = require('./app/logServiceClient')(logger)
var userHandler = require('./app/userHandler')(logServiceClient)
```

userHandler file;

```
module.exports = function(logServiceClient){
    console.log('logServiceClient' + JSON.stringify(logServiceClient))
}
```

Comment: if your modules are having a constructor then you can pass the object to their constructor function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a many ways to *inject* without pulling in the logger from your other modules.

## Use a factory to indirectly create and initialize your objects/modules

```js
function factoryCreateModule() {
  var client = require('client')
  client.$logger = require('logger')
}

function factoryRequireModule(module) {
  var client = require(module)
  client.$logger = require('logger')
}

var client = factoryCreateModule()
client.logger.log('hello')

var client2 = factoryRequireModule('client')
client2.logger.log('hello')
```

## Add your logger to all objects using prototype

Of course you can narrow down the target object...

```js
var logger = {
  log(message) {
    console.log(message)
  },
  warn(message) {
    console.log('!!! ' + message)
  }
}

Object.prototype.$logger = logger

var x = 12;
x.$logger.log('I am a number')

var str = "Hello"
str.$logger.warn('WARNING FROM STRING')
```

## Make your logger global

global is the 'window' in the module system.

```js
// just for snippit to run
window.global = {}

var logger = {
  log(message) {
    console.log(message)
  }
}

// main module
global.$logger = logger

// client module
global.$logger.log('hello world')
```

## Pass the logger into the constructor or init method

```js
var logger = require('logger')

var client = require('client')(logger)

var client2 = require('client2')({logger})

var client3 = require('client3')
client3.init(logger)
```

Answer (score 1):

// file1.js

```
var foo = "bar";
exports.foo = foo;
```

//file2.js

```
var myModule = require('./file1');
var foo = myModule.foo;
```